# how to create a dict from two lists in python3

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two `list` like these:

```
first_list=[{
             'a': 2,
             'c': '[53, 94, 58]'
            },
            {
             'a': 3,
             'c': '[81, 43, 38]'
            }]
```

and

```
second_list=[{
            "d" : 2,
            "e" : "name_two",
            "f":True
            },
            {
            "d" : 3,
            "e" : "name_three",
            "f":False
            }]
```

How can I create this 'dict' :

```
{"name_two": [53, 94, 58],
 "name_three": [53, 94, 58]}
```

and add it to a other `dict` like this :

```
{
"x" : {
    "foo":some_values
    "name_two":[53, 94, 58]
    "name_three":[81, 43, 38]
     }
"y" : ["name_two","name_two"]
}
```

Comment: `How can I create this 'dict'`... good question, what've you tried in the way of answering it?

Comment: How are `'x'`, `'y'` and `some_values` generated programmatically? Are the keys of x always the value of the key `'e'` in the dicts in the first_list? Construction should be easy enough - it's figuring out the logic that's difficult here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict` as the example dictionary to insert to:

```
>>> dict={"x":{"foo":"some_values"},"y":["name_two","name_two"]}
>>> dict
{'x': {'foo': 'some_values'}, 'y': ['name_two', 'name_two']}
>>> dict['x']={**dict['x'],**{y['e']:x['c'] for x,y in zip(first_list,second_list)}}
>>> dict
{'x': {'foo': 'some_values', 'name_two': '[53, 94, 58]', 'name_three': '[81, 43, 38]'}, 'y': ['name_two', 'name_two']}
```

In this example, the number lists are left as strings - you can see in another solution an option for converting these strings to integer lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) your two lists together then it is easy enough to read the fields from the dicts like:

#### Code:

```
new_dict = dict((y['e'], json.loads(x['c']))
                for x, y in zip(first_list, second_list))
```

#### Test Code:

```
first_list = [
    {'a': 2, 'c': '[53, 94, 58]'},
    {'a': 3, 'c': '[81, 43, 38]'}
]

second_list = [
    {"d": 2, "e": "name_two", "f": True},
    {"d": 3, "e": "name_three", "f": False}
]

import json
new_dict = dict((y['e'], json.loads(x['c']))
                for x, y in zip(first_list, second_list))

print(new_dict)
```

I will leave the adding it to another dict as an exercise

#### Test Results:

```
{'name_two': [53, 94, 58], 'name_three': [81, 43, 38]}
```